# Raw wise Cumulative sum of Dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

This is the **input** DF

| origin | destination | 10+ Days | 10 Days | 9 Days | 8 Days | 7 Days | 6 Days | 5 Days | 4 Days | 3 Days | 2 Days | 1 Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CWCJ | MDCC | 66 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 13 | 8 | 11 | 2 | 63 |
| CWCJ | PPSP | 21 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 13 | 8 | 8 | 2 | 3 |
| PCWD | MDCC | 50 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| PCWD | PPSP | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 39 |
| DPMT | JNPT | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 21 |
| PMKM | PPSP | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| PMKM | MDCC | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

i am trying to convert input into following output using cumulative sum. (cumulative sum starts from 10+ days column)

| oirigin | destination | 10+days | 8-Aug | 9-Aug | 10-Aug | 11-Aug | 12-Aug | 13-Aug | 14-Aug | 15-Aug | 16-Aug | 17-Aug | 18-Aug |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CWCJ | MDCC | 66 | 66 | 66 | 66 | 66 | 68 | 69 | 82 | 90 | 101 | 103 | 166 |
| CWCJ | PPSP | 21 | 21 | 21 | 21 | 21 | 23 | 24 | 37 | 45 | 53 | 55 | 58 |
| PCWD | MDCC | 50 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 50 |
| PCWD | PPSP | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 42 |
| DPMT | JNPT | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 21 |
| PMKM | PPSP | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| PMKM | MDCC | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

column name should be todays date , todays date +1 , todays date+2.... todays date +10

i have tried folliwing pyspark/python code however it is not giving expected output.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

todays_date = datetime.today().date()
future_dates = [todays_date + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(1, 12)]

columns_to_sum = ["9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"]

window_spec = Window.orderBy("origin", "destination")

for i, date in enumerate(future_dates):
    col_name = date.strftime("%d-%b")
    for col in columns_to_sum:
        summary_export_dwell_df_temp = summary_export_dwell_df_temp.withColumn(col_name, F.when(F.col(col) > 0, F.sum(col).over(window_spec)).otherwise(0).cast("int"))
    window_spec = Window.orderBy("origin", "destination")

selected_columns = ["origin", "destination", "10+"] + [date.strftime("%d-%b") for date in future_dates]
selected_df = summary_export_dwell_df_temp.select(*selected_columns)

selected_df.show()
```

however, i think there is mistake in cumulative sum logic, for which i need you guys inputs as well as for the date logic after implementing cumulative sum.

below **output** i am getting

| origin | destination | 10+ | 09-Aug | 10-Aug | 11-Aug | 12-Aug | 13-Aug | 14-Aug | 15-Aug | 16-Aug | 17-Aug | 18-Aug | 19-Aug |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CWCJ | MDCC | 66 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| CWCJ | PPSP | 21 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| DPMT | JNPT | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| PCWD | MDCC | 50 | 42 | 42 | 42 | 42 | 42 | 42 | 42 | 42 | 42 | 42 | 42 |
| PCWD | PPSP | 0 | 63 | 63 | 63 | 63 | 63 | 63 | 63 | 63 | 63 | 63 | 63 |
| PMKM | MDCC | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| PMKM | PPSP | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Total |  | 139 | 126 | 126 | 126 | 126 | 126 | 126 | 126 | 126 | 126 | 126 | 126 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the `pandas` tag:

```
df = df.set_index(["origin", "destination"])
df = df.cumsum(axis=1).reset_index()
```

Or if it's always from the second column:

```
df.iloc[:,2:] = df.iloc[:,2:].cumsum(axis=1)
```

To rename the columns with dates starting with today's date:

```
df.columns = list(df.columns[:3])+[dt.strftime("%d-%b") for dt in pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp.today(),freq="D",periods=10)]
```

###### Output:

```
>>> df
  origin destination  10+ Days  08-Aug  ...  14-Aug  15-Aug  16-Aug  17-Aug
0   CWCJ        MDCC        66      66  ...      90     101     103     166
1   CWCJ        PPSP        21      21  ...      45      53      55      58
2   PCWD        MDCC        50      50  ...      50      50      50      50
3   PCWD        PPSP         0       0  ...       0       3       3      42
4   DPMT        JNPT         0       0  ...       0       0       0      21
5   PMKM        PPSP         0       0  ...       0       0       0       0
6   PMKM        MDCC         2       2  ...       2       2       2       2

[7 rows x 13 columns]
```

###### Input df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'origin': ['CWCJ', 'CWCJ', 'PCWD', 'PCWD', 'DPMT', 'PMKM', 'PMKM'],
    'destination': ['MDCC', 'PPSP', 'MDCC', 'PPSP', 'JNPT', 'PPSP', 'MDCC'],
    '10+ Days': [66, 21, 50, 0, 0, 0, 2],
    '10 Days': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '9 Days': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '8 Days': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '7 Days': [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '6 Days': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '5 Days': [13, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '4 Days': [8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '3 Days': [11, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
    '2 Days': [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '1 Day': [63, 3, 0, 39, 21, 0, 0]
    })
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iloc'` and `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'set_index'
` i am using databriks notebook

Comment: You should be using a `pandas` DataFrame. `df = pysparkDf.toPandas()`

Comment: not working man, `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str`

Comment: Are your values in the columns stored as `str`? If so, use `df.iloc[:,2:] = df.iloc[:,2:].astype(float).cumsum(axis=1)`

Comment: how to implement date logic as well as origin destination column

Comment: What date logic? None of this was in your question. You asked for help with the "cumulative sum logic"

Comment: Also, your input has 13 columns and your output has 14. Why?

Comment: Output should be `origin, destination, 10+, todays date, todays date +1,... + todays date +10'

Comment: @vish - I already implemented that.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Pivot, unpivot` spark inbuilt functions for this case.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import *
w= Window.partitionBy("origin","destination").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

#sample data
df = spark.createDataFrame([('CWCJ','MDCC','66','0','0','0','2','1','13','8','11','2','63')],
                           ['origin','destination','10+ Days','10 Days','9 Days','8 Days','7 Days','6 Days','5 Days','4 Days','3 Days','2 Days','1 Day'])
df.show()   
#+------+-----------+--------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
#|origin|destination|10+ Days|10 Days|9 Days|8 Days|7 Days|6 Days|5 Days|4 Days|3 Days|2 Days|1 Day|
#+------+-----------+--------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
#|  CWCJ|       MDCC|      66|      0|     0|     0|     2|     1|    13|     8|    11|     2|   63|
#+------+-----------+--------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+


sum_df = df.select(col('origin'),col('destination'),expr("""stack(11,'10+ Days',`10+ Days`,'10 Days',`10 Days`,'9 Days',`9 Days`,'8 Days',`8 Days`,'7 Days',`7 Days`,'6 Days',`6 Days`,'5 Days',`5 Days`,'4 Days',`4 Days`,'3 Days',`3 Days`,'2 Days',`2 Days`,'1 Day',`1 Day`)""")).\
                             withColumn("mid", monotonically_increasing_id()).\
  withColumn("sum", sum("col1").over(w)).\
    withColumn("rn", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("origin","destination").orderBy("mid"))-2).\
      withColumn("dt",when(col("rn")>=0, expr("date_format(date_add(current_date,rn),'dd-MMM')")).otherwise(col("col0")))

sum_df.groupBy("origin","destination").pivot("dt").agg(first(col("sum"))).show()
#+------+-----------+------+------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
#|origin|destination|08-Aug|09-Aug|10+ Days|10-Aug|11-Aug|12-Aug|13-Aug|14-Aug|15-Aug|16-Aug|17-Aug|
#+------+-----------+------+------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
#|  CWCJ|       MDCC|  66.0|  66.0|    66.0|  66.0|  68.0|  69.0|  82.0|  90.0| 101.0| 103.0| 166.0|
#+------+-----------+------+------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
`

Comment: Can u run the above code and let me know if there are any issues..?

Answer (score 0):

you could employ `reduce()` from functools.

here's an example taking first 2 rows from your question's input sample

```py
from functools import reduce
import datetime
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

sumcols = [k for k in data_sdf.columns if 'day' in k.lower()]
# ['10+ Days', '10 Days', '9 Days', '8 Days', '7 Days', '6 Days', '5 Days', '4 Days', '3 Days', '2 Days', '1 Day']

# column rename logic
cname_logic = lambda x: (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=x)).strftime('%d-%b')

data_sdf. \
    select('origin', 'destination', 
           *[reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [func.col(c) for c in sumcols[0:i+1]]).alias(cname_logic(i)) for i in range(len(sumcols))]
           ). \
    show()

# +------+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
# |origin|destination|08-Aug|09-Aug|10-Aug|11-Aug|12-Aug|13-Aug|14-Aug|15-Aug|16-Aug|17-Aug|18-Aug|
# +------+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
# |  CWCJ|       MDCC|    66|    66|    66|    66|    68|    69|    82|    90|   101|   103|   166|
# |  CWCJ|       PPSP|    21|    21|    21|    21|    23|    24|    37|    45|    53|    55|    58|
# +------+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

---

the `reduce` function generates the columnar sums.

```py
[reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [func.col(c) for c in sumcols[0:i+1]]).alias(sumcols[i]) for i in range(len(sumcols))]

# [Column<'10+ Days AS `10+ Days`'>,
#  Column<'(10+ Days + 10 Days) AS `10 Days`'>,
#  Column<'((10+ Days + 10 Days) + 9 Days) AS `9 Days`'>,
#  Column<'(((10+ Days + 10 Days) + 9 Days) + 8 Days) AS `8 Days`'>,
#  Column<'((((10+ Days + 10 Days) + 9 Days) + 8 Days) + 7 Days) AS `7 Days`'>,
#  Column<'(((((10+ Days + 10 Days) + 9 Days) + 8 Days) + 7 Days) + 6 Days) AS `6 Days`'>,
#  Column<'((((((10+ Days + 10 Days) + 9 Days) + 8 Days) + 7 Days) + 6 Days) + 5 Days) AS `5 Days`'>,
#  Column<'(((((((10+ Days + 10 Days) + 9 Days) + 8 Days) + 7 Days) + 6 Days) + 5 Days) + 4 Days) AS `4 Days`'>,
#  Column<'((((((((10+ Days + 10 Days) + 9 Days) + 8 Days) + 7 Days) + 6 Days) + 5 Days) + 4 Days) + 3 Days) AS `3 Days`'>,
#  Column<'(((((((((10+ Days + 10 Days) + 9 Days) + 8 Days) + 7 Days) + 6 Days) + 5 Days) + 4 Days) + 3 Days) + 2 Days) AS `2 Days`'>,
#  Column<'((((((((((10+ Days + 10 Days) + 9 Days) + 8 Days) + 7 Days) + 6 Days) + 5 Days) + 4 Days) + 3 Days) + 2 Days) + 1 Day) AS `1 Day`'>]
```